# "LEFT" is not valid at this position, expecting ';' - SQL Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, procedure

For the following SQL query,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addPayments()
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO payment (pay_date, salary_amount, employee_id)
       SELECT curdate(), designation.salary, employee.id
       FROM employee   LEFT INNER JOIN designation
       ON employee.designation_id=designation.id;
END
```

I received this error.

```
"Left" is not valid at this position, expecting ';'
```

Can anyone please point out What am i doing wrong here? and correct the statement :)

[Followed this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629785/how-to-select-and-insert-values-in-mysql-using-stored-procedures)

Comment: There is no `LEFT INNER` join.

Comment: I don't get it. im relatively new to this

Comment: A LEFT join is not the same as an INNER join. You can't define a join as LEFT INNER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such thing as an LEFT INNER JOIN they are always `LEFT OUT JOIN`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE addPayments()
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO payment (pay_date, salary_amount, employee_id)
       SELECT curdate(), designation.salary, employee.id
       FROM employee LEFT JOIN designation
       ON employee.designation_id=designation.id;
END
```